# Returning null id while setting up the data in FireStore

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

```
createPostInFireStore({String medaiURl, String location, String description}) async{
    await postsRef.doc(widget.currentUser.id).collection("userposts").doc(_postId).set(
             {"postId": _postId,
          "ownerId": widget.currentUser.id,
          "userName": widget.currentUser.username,
          "mediaurl": medaiURl,
          "description": description,
          "location": location,
          "timeStamp": dateTimeStamp,   
        },
        //SetOptions(merge : true),
    );
  
  }
```

Error Message:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'id' was called on null.
E/flutter (23730): Receiver: null
E/flutter (23730): Tried calling: id
E/flutter (23730): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
E/flutter (23730): #1      _UploadState.createPostInFireStore (package:chat_ui/Components/social_app_homepage.dart:397:43)
E/flutter (23730): #2      _UploadState.handleSumitPost (package:chat_ui/Components/social_app_homepage.dart:420:3)
E/flutter (23730): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (23730): #3      _UploadState.buildLoadingScreen.<anonymous closure> (package:chat_ui/Components/social_app_homepage.dart:443:51)
E/flutter (23730): #4      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:993:19)
E/flutter (23730): #5      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1111:38)
E/flutter (23730): #6      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:183:24)
E/flutter (23730): #7      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:598:11)
E/flutter (23730): #8      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:287:5)
E/flutter (23730): #9      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:222:7)
E/flutter (23730): #10     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:476:9)
E/flutter (23730): #11     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:77:12)
E/flutter (23730): #12     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:122:9)
E/flutter (23730): #13     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:377:8)
E/flutter (23730): #14     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:120:18)
E/flutter (23730): #15     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:106:7)
E/flutter (23730): #16     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:358:19)
E/flutter (23730): #17     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:338:22)
E/flutter (23730): #18     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:267:11)
E/flutter (23730): #19     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:295:7)
E/flutter (23730): #20     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:240:7)
E/flutter (23730): #21     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:213:7)
E/flutter (23730): #22     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1206:13)
E/flutter (23730): #23     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
E/flutter (23730): #24     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:7)
E/flutter (23730): #25     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:265:10)
E/flutter (23730): #26     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:174:5)
E/flutter (23730):
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure that `widget.currentUser` has value before calling the `createPostInFireStore` medthod